# Unsupported Array error when reading JDBC source in (Py)Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to convert postgreSQL DB to Dataframe . Following is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Connect to DB") \
    .getOrCreate()

jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://XXXXXX" 
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : " ",
  "password" : " ",
  "driver" : "org.postgresql.Driver"
}

query = "(SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables) XXX"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=query, properties=connectionProperties)

table_name_list = df.select("table_name").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect() 
    for table_name in table_name_list:
          df2 = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=table_name, properties=connectionProperties)
```

Error I am getting :

> java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type ARRAY on generating df2 for table name

If I hard code table name value , I do not get the same error

```
df2 = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl,"conditions",properties=connectionProperties)
```

I checked table_name type and it is String , is this the correct approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you don't want the table names that belong to internal working of postgres such as `pg_type`, `pg_policies` etc whose schema are of type `pg_catalog` that causes the error

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.jdbc.
>   : java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type ARRAY

when you try to read them as

```
spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table='pg_type', properties=connectionProperties)
```

and there are tables such as `applicable_roles`, `view_table_usage` etc whose schema are of type `information_schema` that causes

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.jdbc.
>   : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "view_table_usage" does not exist

when you try to read them as

```
spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table='view_table_usage', properties=connectionProperties)
```

The tables whose schema types are public can be read into tables using above jdbc commands.

> > I checked table_name type and it is String , is this the correct approach ?

So you need to *filter out* those table names and apply your logic as

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Connect to DB") \
    .getOrCreate()

jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:post/" 
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : " ",
  "password" : " ",
  "driver" : "org.postgresql.Driver"
}

query = "information_schema.tables"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=query, properties=connectionProperties)

table_name_list = df.filter((df["table_schema"] != 'pg_catalog') & (df["table_schema"] != 'information_schema')).select("table_name").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect() 
    for table_name in table_name_list:
          df2 = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=table_name, properties=connectionProperties)
```

That should work