# backend scala can't load dataframe while using the Presto driver _ java.sql.Exception

Tags: scala, hive, hdfs, presto, trino

This is where the test break.

```scala
       var df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
                .option("url", url_ )
                .option("dbtable", dbtable_ )
                .option("driver", "com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver")
                .load()
```

The exception message that I got: The same message was thrown even with prestosql version 326 JDBC driver.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type ARRAY
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getCatalystType(JdbcUtils.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$8.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:316)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$8.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:316)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.getSchema(JdbcUtils.scala:315)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:63)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
  ... 49 elided
```

Comment: Can you try Presto JDBC 326 (https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.prestosql/presto-jdbc/326/jar) and share the stacktrace of the failure?

Comment: I think this is known issue of Spark. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613977/unsupported-array-error-when-reading-jdbc-source-in-pyspark https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a834dba120e3569e44c5e4b9f8db9c6eef58161b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L205 Either way, I agree with upgrading to the latest Presto version.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I used the new jar and the stack trace is the same one as the old one

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace for Presto JDBC 326?

Comment: Also, if the error comes from JDBC, you may want to file the issue directly @ https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues.